# Order Detail page in My Account - Magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone help me?

In `My Account->My Order` page, it's displaying all orders in a table, but if I click the `View Order` link, it's not redirecting to another page - it's staying in the same page.

The link is correct (`http://.../index.php/sales/order/view/order_id/142/`) but it's still not redirecting to the `Order Details` page.

I am using magento 1.4.1. If you need any more details, I'll provide them but please help me with this. Is there any setting that means that the Order Details page won't display?

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you edited the dashboard templates?
What errors are reported in your debug console like firebug?

Greetings